# How do you create an association table with an auto increment primary key in SQLAlchemy for Flask?

Tags: python, sqlite, flask, sqlalchemy

I am trying to create a virtual version of the board game Mastermind in Flask. Since I need to store information about the current game state, I am using SQLAlchemy with SQLite to achieve this goal.

A game has a random generated code that the user has to guess. This code consists of various colors that could be duplicate. Because a color can be used for multiple games, it is a many-to-many relationship. So what I have done is created an association table between Game and Color.

```
game_colors = db.Table("game_colors",
    db.Column("id", db.Integer, primary_key=True),
    db.Column("game_id", db.Integer, db.ForeignKey("game.id")),
    db.Column("color_id", db.Integer, db.ForeignKey("color.id"))
)
```

I have added an id field as the primary key so that a color combination from a game can consist of duplicate colors. Now the strange part is that when I commit my changes to the database after adding a few duplicate colors to a game, they will not be saved. It seems like it is not making use of the id field at all.

How can I make the id field the primary key or make sure that I can store duplicate colors in this association table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So what I did is change the Table to a Model.

```
class GameColor(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    game_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('game.id'), nullable=False)
    color_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('color.id'), nullable=False)

    game = db.relationship('Game', back_populates='game_colors')
    color = db.relationship('Color', back_populates='game_colors')
```

In this model the id field is actually being used and all duplicate records are saved after committing the changes. This solution is not as viable as I would have hoped, since you can't directly call all the colors a game may have. In this case you'd have to loop over `game.game_colors` and then call the `color` from each `game_color`.